# IIS Rewrite Module: Change set-cookie path rule

Tags: iis, cookies, url-rewriting, arr

I am modifying my tor reverse proxy in IIS so that it must be accessed through a php page in my cgi-bin.

Here's where I'm stuck: I need to change the path value of all cookies set by the reverse proxy.

Example:

I request /cgi-bin/tor.php?url=easycoinsayj7p5l.onion/register.php in my browser. A backend local request is made to /tor/easycoinsayj7p5l.onion/register.php. A php session cookie is set with the path=/tor/easycoinsayj7p5l.onion/. This cookie does not set properly because the request is being made by /cgi-bin/tor.php. The path needs to be changed to /cgi-bin/ so the cookie can be set and accessed.

Below is the rule I've come up with to change this in the outbound requests section, however, it doesnt seem to do anything.

```
                <rule name="rewritecookiepath" preCondition="" enabled="true">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern="(.*)(Path=(.*); )(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1} Path=/cgi-bin/; {R:4}" />
                </rule>
```

Please advise me what I'm missing!
-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The rule works fine on my side.

[image]

So please enable failed request tracing and it will show the root cause. I asssume there was something wrong with the value of Set-Cookie header.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules#:~:text=If%20the%20Failed%20Request%20Tracing,module%20installer%20in%20repair%20mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules#:%7E:text=If%20the%20Failed%20Request%20Tracing,module%20installer%20in%20repair%20mode).

[image]